# UIImage sizes x1 x2 x3 - How to deal with image sizes from Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, image-size, kingfisher

I've stored three version of each image asset for the app (x1, x2 and x3). This works great with images used statically in the UI etc. However most of the user created images are stored in Firebase/Firestore and I use Kingfisher for image cacheing. Should I store an x1, x2, and x3 version of all images in Firestore or is there a different way to solve multiple screen sizes? What is the most efficient?

Comment: I wouldn't store any images in Firestore.  That's what Cloud Storage is good for.

Comment: You can use a single pdf image instead of x, 2x, and 3x images.

Comment: @lionserdar PDF image?

Comment: @DougStevenson If I use Cloud Storage then I can't access those image from an Android or website application... or?

Comment: @DougStevenson: Correction of my previous comment. 

Ok, so Google Cloud Storage is a better option than Firestore for storing images. Thanks, will look into this. 

That said, do you deal with image sizes differently when using Google Cloud Storage vs locally stored x, x2, x3 images?

Comment: It's up to you to decide what images to store.  Firebase is not opinionated about that.

Comment: @Chris_1983_Norway instead of three different images that are in .png format, you can use only one .pdf. that will satisfy all different sizes. https://useyourloaf.com/blog/creating-scaled-images-with-pdf-vectors/

Comment: @lionserdar thanks for the link. If an app user want to share photos of an activity (eg. photo taken with the iPhone camera) I guess pdf vectors are not the right format?